# Android Camera Intent: Disallow "Retake"?

Tags: android, camera

I use the Android camera Intent to take a picture.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
this.startActivityForResult(intent, GalleryActivity.PHOTO_ACTIVITY);
```

Is there any way to disallow the user to retake the picture and immediately get back to the calling Activity, even without having to press the OK button to accept the image? (I don't wanna have to reimplement the camera activity already provided).

Comment: try MediaStore.IMAGE_CAPTURE instead of MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE

Comment: there's no MediaStore.IMAGE_CAPTURE

Comment: Sorry my bad. try this MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA

Answer (score 0):

Not by using an Intent to capture the photo.

You'll need to use Androids [Camera-Classes](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html).